# regex to replace a pattern in Jenkinsfile (declarative) which has a `&` in the pattern

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have an Ansible Inventory file which has ansible_password value which needs to be replaced by user input

what I have is below in a `windows.yaml`

```
ansible_user=sa_user@somewindowsdomain.external
ansible_password =
```

and I take an userInput from Jenkins, where user enters `&32lihdye34jC5W`

```
parameters {
            password defaultValue: '', description: 'Please Enter ansible_password ', name: 'sa_pass'
                      }

sh 'echo ${sa_pass}'
```

I tried below

```
sed -i "s/ansible_password=.*/ansible_password=${sa_pass}/g" $inventory_path/windows.yaml
```

which doesn't do what I wanted but got below

`ansible_password=ansible_password32lihdye34jC5W`

what I was expecting is

`ansible_password = &32lihdye34jC5W`

Comment: In your yaml file, you write `ansible_password =` yet in your sed command you write `ansible_password=.*` (without a space). Is that a typo in your question or did you also forget the space when you executed the command ?

Comment: It was a typo. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to avoid the `s///`. If you are using GNU sed you can do this:

```
$: a_pass="&32lihdye34jC5W"; echo "foo stuff
ansible_password=ansible_password32lihdye34jC5W
bar stuff" | sed -E "/ansible_password\s*=\s*/ {
                    e echo \"ansible_password = ${sa_pass}\";
                    d; }"
foo stuff
ansible_password = &32lihdye34jC5W
bar stuff
```

GNU `sed`'s `e` is "execute" and runs a subcommand.
The `d` is needed to keep `sed` from printing that record aside from the `e` command.

Another way would be to pre-quote the password with POSIX chracter classes.

```
$: sa_pass="$( echo "&32lihdye34jC5W" |
                 sed 's/[[:punct:]]/\\&/g' )"
   echo "foo stuff
   ansible_password=ansible_password32lihdye34jC5W
   bar stuff" | sed -E "s/ansible_password\s*=\s*.*/ansible_password = ${sa_pass}/"
foo stuff
ansible_password = &32lihdye34jC5W
bar stuff
```

I *think* that should work with non-GNU versions.

Comment: Fixed it in a dirty way :)

```TempVar=`echo $sa_pass | tr -s "&" "<"`

sed -E -i "s/ansible_password/ansible_password=$TempVar/g" windows.yaml

cat windows.yaml | tr -s "<" "&" > windows1.yaml && rm windows.yaml && mv windows1.yaml windows.yaml```

pardon my code formatting.

Comment: If it's a one-time thing, why not just open the file and change the password?